# Hide button using onClick in Functional Components in React.js

Tags: reactjs, button, show-hide, react-functional-component

**By clicking on the button** I need it to **hide de button** all this using Functional components onClick in React.js

[Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/showandhidebuttonreact-868zq)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a local state using [`useState`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html) hook to keep the content hidden between re-renders, and conditionally render content as shown below:

```
import React, {useState} from 'react'
export default function App() {
const [hidden, setHidden] = useState(false);
  return (
     <div className="App">
      <h1>OnClick in the button show and hide</h1>
      {!hidden && <button onClick={() => setHidden(true)}>Click Me</button>}
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit showAndHideButtonReact (forked)]

Comment: I misunderstood the question, updated the answer ^

Comment: How to write for multiple oncllick buttons in Functional Components

Comment: @GaneshGujjeti instead of a boolean, you need to keep an array of objects in the state that represents each item